# Remove newline in text file, when there is a character on the beginning of the next line

Tags: bash, csv, sed

Hello I have a text csv file where some of the lines are "broken" like this:

```
blahblahblah;"- lalalal
- lolololo
- lililili";
```

I have tried the following commands but none of them change anything.

```
sed -i -e 's/\n-//g' sample.txt

sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n-/ /g' sample.txt
```

Correct line should look like this:

```
blahblahblah;"- lalalal - lolololo - lililili";
```

it's ANSI text file with windows EOF format. Maybe that is the problem?

Comment: Can you give an example of a "correct" line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
kent$  echo 'blahblahblah;"- lalalal
- lolololo
- lililili";'|awk '{printf "%s",$0}END{print ""}'
blahblahblah;"- lalalal- lolololo- lililili";
```

or set `ORS`:

```
kent$  echo 'blahblahblah;"- lalalal
- lolololo
- lililili";'|awk -v ORS="" '7;END{print "\n"}'
blahblahblah;"- lalalal- lolololo- lililili";
```

**EDIT**(gawk)

then you gave a bad example. anyway, as you required:

```
kent$  echo 'blahblahblah;"- lalalal
- lolololo
- lililili";'|awk -v RS='\0' -v ORS="" '{gsub(/\n-/,"-")}7'
blahblahblah;"- lalalal- lolololo- lililili";
```

only remove `\n` if next char is `-`

Comment: The "challange" is to not  replace ALL line breaks, but only this, where in the next line is a "- ". =/

Comment: I tried `awk '{printf "%s",$0}END{print ""}' sample.txt > test.txt` no change in test.txt

Comment: @user3084928 chk **EDIT**

Comment: I had to do `dos2unix` afterwards this command works like a charm: `awk -v RS='\0' -v ORS="" '{gsub(/\n-/,"-")}7'`

Comment: okay, somehow it doesn't fully solve my problem, because there are lines left, which don't start with an `-`... So the correct definition would be remove any line breaks when the next line is NOT starting with a digit. Anybody help? =/

Answer (score 0):

Using `gnu awk` you can do:

```
awk '{gsub(/\n-/, "-", $0); print $0}' RS=';\n' file
blahblahblah;"- lalalal- lolololo- lililili"
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps on mac osx? If so, you need to use gsed (GNU sed). This works fine for me (using your expression with only small change to replacement as indicated in your edit):

```
gsed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n-/ -/g' sample.txt
blahblahblah;"- lalalal - lolololo - lililili";
```

Comment: it's ANSI text file with windows EOF format. Maybe that is the problem?

Comment: what is your OS. are you on windows/cygwin?

Comment: if not, then run perhaps run the file through dos2unix to make sure it's UNIX end-of-line format (which is what I assume you meant).

Comment: no I am on CentOS, but the CSV is been created on a windows system. =/